# How to regroup two <td> vertically and add icon before them?

Tags: html, css

I"m working to create a responsive table for emails, it looks on large screens like this :

[image]

In mobile screens I displayed `tr` content (td)  vertically using `flex-direction: column` like this :

[image]

Because I want to add an icon before the sender `td1` & receiver `td2` like this:

[image]

I could not regroup **aaa@examle.com** & **zzz.@example.com** `tds` together then add icon before them using `::before`.

Is there someone who could just give me a basic example of a CSS trick to regroup them together ?

Comment: use the before on td1 and use a margin-left on the td2

Comment: the before with position absolute